# Insert link with yii framework

Tags: php, yii, hyperlink

I'm developing a web app with yii framework in php.

In html code i have something like this:

```
<a href="search.php" class="btn_buscar">
    <h3>Search</h3>
    <div class="icon_menu">
    </div>
</a>
```

¿ How can I do that with CHtml::link in yii framework?

Thank you :)

Comment: Does [the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#link-detail) leave you with unanswered questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo CHtml::link('<h3>Search</h3><div class="icon_menu"></div>','search.php',array('class'=>'btn_buscar'));
```